Lower bound on injectivity radius of a closed manifold with bounded diameter
I’m interested in a closed Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ with $sec<0$ and $diam(M)\leq D$. My question is:
If at some point $p\in M^n$, the injectivity radius $injrad(p)\geq1$, then can we get $injrad(M^n)\geq C(n,D)$, for some constant depending on dimension and diameter?
I guess this is true, since if a negatively curved manifold has a very thin part ($injrad$ very small), then the thin part seems to be far away from the thick part ($injrad\geq1$). Does anyone know whether this is true or not?
Any comments are welcomed.

Yes, if you assume negative pinching, you get a bound which also depends on the pinching constants.

@MoisheKohan  Can you give a reference for this result?

This follows from the Margulis lemma, see the book by Ballmann, Gromov and Schroeder.

By the way, do not post the same question simultaneously here and on Mathoverflow.

@MoisheKohan Thank you for your  comments. But Margulis lemma implies that if injrad attains a maximum, then this maximum has a lower bound. Actually, I came up with this question precisely because I saw this conclusion in their book.

You should use not this consequence but Margulis lemma itself, combined with the fact that the nearest-point projection to a geodesic in a Hadamard manifold of curvature $\le a<0$ is exponentially contracting.
